# Why is PostConstruct not called?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am working on a simple Java EE application.

I have class like this:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

@Stateless
public class BlogEntryDao {

    EntityManager em;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistence");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void addNewEntry(){
        Blogentry blogentry = new Blogentry();
        
        blogentry.setTitle("Test");
        blogentry.setContent("asdfasfas");

        em.persist(blogentry);

    }
}
```

So my managed bean calls this method. Until here no problems. But since the initialize method is not called, I am getting an NPE in **em.persist**.

Why is the initialize method not being called? I am running this on Glassfish server.

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't be opening your `EntityManager` in a global scope; the `EntityManager` roughly corresponds to a session. If you really need to handle your own session management (injecting @PersistenceContext is better), you should be creating and closing an `EntityManager` in each call to `addNewEntry`.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your container is treating the object as something requiring dependency injection? Not every object gets hooked into, and if you're just calling `new BlogEntryDao()` somewhere, the container may not know to initialize it as a bean.

Comment: @chrylis Yeah thanks, I am calling new BlogEntryDao actually.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks, changing it to EJB BlogEntryDao fixed it. Can you please proivde an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I think you can define init-method="initialize" in the bean configuration file.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Java EE bean annotations such as `@PostConstruct` only apply to container-managed beans. If you are simply calling `new BlogEntryDao` yourself, the container isn't going to intercept the creation and call the `@PostConstruct` method.

(Furthermore, you'd be better off using `@PersistenceContext` or `@PersistenceUnit` instead of manually fetching the `EntityManagerFactory` in your `initialize()` method, and you should be creating an `EntityManager` for each call to `addNewEntry()`, since they're short-lived. Making these changes would eliminate the need for `initialize()` at all.)

Answer (score 19):

Since this question comes up first on Google for "postconstruct not called", another reason a `@PostConstruct` method might not be called besides using the `new` keyword instead of putting `@PostConstruct` in a Spring bean is if you have a circular dependency.

If this bean were to depend on another bean that depended on this bean, your other bean might call `addNewEntry()` before `BlogEntryDao` was initialized, even though BlogEntryDao is a dependency for that other bean.

This is because Spring didn't know which bean you wanted to load first due to the circular reference.  In this case, one can remove the circular reference or use `@AutoWired`/`@Value` constructor parameters instead of member values or setters, or if using xml configuration, maybe you can swap the order in which the beans are defined.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem in my application.
You didn't post your bean context configuration xml file (so I'm not sure if it's the same issue) but in my case adding this line:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Solved my problem.
You need either `<context:annotation-config/>` or `<context:component-scan/>` to enable @PostConstruct annotation.

Comment: Note: this is correct for Spring applications but the question was about general JavaEE applications.

Answer (score 6):

In my case @PostConstruct was not called because my initialize() method was static and was also throwing an exception. In either case the method is ignored. I hope it helps someone else who made the same mistake.
This can be found in the console:

```
WARNING: JSF1044: Method '<XXX>' marked with the 'javax.annotation.PostConstruct' annotation cannot be static.  This method will be ignored.
WARNING: JSF1047: Method '<XXX>' marked with the 'javax.annotation.PostConstruct' annotation cannot declare any checked exceptions.  This method will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 4):

When using Spring make sure you are using the right PostConstruct annotation from the right package.

```
javax.annotation.PostConstruct
```

should be the one. Not for example:

```
jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct
```

It took me a little while to figure out why only one of my PostConstruct didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In my case `@PostConstruct` method was not called because I was referencing to a `public instance variable` of the spring service bean directly in other service beans (ie myService.myProperty). When i made a public `getter method` for the property (ie `getMyProperty()`) and used that to get the property the `@PostConstruct` method was called again. Also I made `myProperty` `private` to prevent any accidental direct referencing in the future.

Also note that if you don't explicitly register the class with `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` annotated class and rely soley on `@Autowired` instead, the `@PostConstruct` method may not be executed immediately on startup. Only when one of the methods of the autowired class are referenced and called by another class will that class be loaded and only at that time will the `@PostConstruct` method be called. In other words, by only using `@Autowired` you are essentially lazy loading a class. If you want to load it at startup, register it with `@Bean`

Heres a good SO thread about the difference between `@Bean` and `@Autowired` [Difference between @Bean and @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172888/difference-between-bean-and-autowired)

EDIT: One last remark. When you have a webapplication and decided to annotate your class with `@RequestScope` then the `@Postconstruct` annotated method will be called each time when a new request comes in. This is because `@RequestScope` instructs spring to create a new `instance` of the class every time a new request comes in. If you want all requests to use the same instance, then you could use `@Bean` as mentioned above, but you could also use the annotation `@Singleton` above your class. This will cause the class to be loaded eagerly upon startup.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had two instances of `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` inside classpath. One was bundled with the war package and another was provided by tomcat. When Spring is scanning for the `@PostConstruct` annotation it compares these two different instances. Therefore the `@PostConstruct` annotated method was not picked while scanning.

Providing only one instance of `javax.annotation-api` library solved the issue.

Comment: How one can do that? How to provide only one instance of the library?

Comment: for me, i had a multi-module project and the module containing the main function was scanning another module and the pom of both modules had this dependency, removing the dependency from pom containing the main function (since it was not using postconstruct) corrected the problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the class having `@Postconstruct` method lies within the same package. I moved class file to main package and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the ways are already mentioned. However one can also create a bean in the config file for the class

> org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

;

This will enable *PostConstruct* and *PreDestroy* annotations.

> ```
> <bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>
> ```

Also for *Predestroy* one needs to call *context.registerShutDownHook()*