# A method with @Bean autowires without @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

In my Java Config file there is

```
@Bean
public CDPlayer cdPlayer(CompactDisc compactDisc){
    return new CDPlayer(compactDisc);
}
```

My book says that the (singleton) CompactDisc is autowired into the method. Why? Because I do not see `@Autowired`. How can this work?

Comment: Starting with Spring 4.3 you don't need to use @Autowired annotation to inject dependency

Comment: This question explain the difference between the two : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172888/difference-between-bean-and-autowired

Answer (score 5):

About [`@Bean` in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-dependencies)

> A @Bean annotated method can have an arbitrary number of parameters describing the dependencies required to build that bean
>
> The resolution mechanism is pretty much identical to constructor-based dependency injection, see the relevant section for more details.

Every parameter in a `@Bean` method will be resolved (injected by Spring container).