# @PostConstruct fails to be called when combined with Spring Batch readers

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, postconstruct

I've been trying to implement `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` methods in an `Account` class of mine. Neither of them worked in the following situation, but for the sake of brevity, I'll only talk about `@PostConstruct`.

I'm using Spring Batch's readers to load these accounts from a fixed-length file. So far, so good, except when my reader creates these accounts, it apparently does not call the `@PostConstruct` method (debug breakpoints are never activated, and log messages are not printed out).
The reader is only custom in the sense that it's a custom class extending `FlatFileItemReader<Account>` and setting values in the constructor.

Adding the exact same initialization method (that never got called in the `Account` class) to the reader itself works just fine.
I.e. if the `@PostConstruct` method should be called upon *reader* initialization, it works. Just not when the reader itself initializes accounts annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

If I add a breakpoint or log message in the constructor of `Account` directly, it also works without an issue.

---

### Is this desired behaviour by Spring Batch? Or could this be caused by any configuration of mine?

[Another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161682/why-is-postconstruct-not-called) mentioned that annotations such as `@PostConstruct` "only apply to container-managed beans", not if "you are simply calling `new BlogEntryDao()` yourself".

Is this what's happening here - Spring Batch calling `new Account(...)` directly, without registering them in the container? After all, I never have these accounts available as beans or anything.

Comment: See @Ivans answer.  If an `Account` represents a line of the file, then what additional logic needs to be done in a post construct or pre destroy `Account` method?  Does that logic really belong within `Account`?  What is the logic?

Comment: In my concrete use case, I merely wanted to try out the `PostConstruct` and `PreDestroy` annotations, and randomly picked this class. I'm actually not sure if there's a real-world use case where these methods would be preferable to another step in the job. Nevertheless, I'm curious as to why they're not called.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `Account` class annotated with `@Component`, `@Bean` or `@Service`? If you create objects of account class like `Account c = new Account()` the nSpring doesn't know about creation of such objects. Because of that Spring doesn't call method annotated with `@postConstruct`

Comment: No, my `Account` class is not annotated with `@Component` & Co. Nevertheless, *I myself* never call `new Account()`, creating the accounts is handled by the `ItemReader` implementations provided by Spring Batch by default. My guess is that the issue lies somewhere within this implementation, I'm just not sure if it's not supposed to work by design or not.

Comment: @PixelMaster PostConstruct method is called only for objects created inside Spring context by Spring IoC container

Answer (score 1):

> when my reader creates these accounts, it apparently does not call the @PostConstruct method

`@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` methods are called by the Spring container after creating and before destroying the instance of your bean. If your object is not managed by Spring, those methods will not be called.

> I'm using Spring Batch's readers to load these accounts from a fixed-length file

In this case, you should have already configured a `FieldSetMapper` to map fields to an `Account` instance. If you use the `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`, you can set the `PrototypeBeanName` which is the name of a bean (for example of type `Account`) of scope prototype (so that an instance is created for each line). This way, `Account` instances will be managed by Spring, used by Spring Batch reader, and your method annotated with `PostConstruct` will be called. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Account account() {
    return new Account();
}

@Bean
public BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Account> beanMapper() {
    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Account> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    fieldSetMapper.setPrototypeBeanName("account");
    return fieldSetMapper;
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Account> accountReader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Account>()
            .name("accountsItemReader")
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("accounts.txt"))
            .fixedLength()
            .columns(new Range[] {new Range(1, 1), new Range(2, 4)})
            .names(new String[]{"id", "name"})
            .fieldSetMapper(beanMapper())
            .build();
}
```

More details about this in the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.html#setPrototypeBeanName-java.lang.String-).

Hope this helps.